# How to add product updated date as sort order using custom extension

Tags: magento-1.9, module, sorting, list-view

I want to add `product updated date` as `sort` order but I don't want to add `Updated date field` in `product setting` page which means if `admin` `updates` a `product`, it's `edited date` should be detected automatically.

**Ref:**
[image]

I want to achieve this using `custom module`.

I am using `magento 1.9.0.1`.

Comment: Magento provide in built field "updated_at" in table "catalog_product_entity", you can used that field. You need to overide list.php file to in custom extension to override sorting functionlity work with this field.

Comment: Which `function` I should  `override` in `list.php` ?

Comment: I added answer please check and if it used full please mark as solution, so other also get help.

Answer (score 0):

Magento provide in built field "updated_at" in table "catalog_product_entity", you can used that field. You need to overide list.php file to in custom extension to override sorting functionlity work with this field.

For List.php override, you need to do following code :

In your extension config.xml file write following :

```
<blocks>
      <myextension>
        <class>Mymodule_Myextension_Block</class>
      </myextension>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_list_toolbar>Mymodule_Myextension_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Toolbar</product_list_toolbar>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
    </blocks>
```

And create Block file Mymodule/Myextension/Block/Catalog/Product/List/Toolbar.php code:

```
<?php
class Mymodule_Myextension_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Toolbar extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
{
}
?>
```

And there is function _getProductCollection() which create collection, you need to customized this collection.

Comment: You asked to override `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar` but  `_getProductCollection()` is not located inside this `class`,how is it possible? also I want `Updated date` should be visible in drop-down like `price`.

Comment: If possible, provide full answer otherwise it will take much time to understand.

Comment: Here is the complete path of file :
app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php

And check line no. 56 there is a function protected function _getProductCollection().